# Como llamar al id que crea firestore para poder borrar documentos? react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firestore

estoy haciendo un proyecto en react js en el cual utilizo firestore. Puedo subir y ver los datos pero no borrarlos. Yo creo que el problema esta en que no puedo acceder al ID que genera automaticamente firestore y por eso no puedo borrarlos, pero tampoco se como poder acceder a ese ID

Asi subo los datos (no le asigno un id):

```
 const subida = async (precio) => {
       const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "Tobi"), {
        dia: prec.reduce((prev, current) => prev + current),
      });
      console.log(docRef.id)
    };
    subida();
```

Asi los llamo para ver

```
const obtenerServicios = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "Tobi"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const docs = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push({ ...doc.data() });
      });
      setDia(docs);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerServicios();
  }, []);
```

Asi para intentar borrarlos

```
  const borrarServicio = async () => {
    const borrarFirestore = async (id) => {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "Tobi", "aca tendria que llamar al id"));

    };
    borrarFirestore();
  };
```

el problema es que no se como acceder al docRef.id desde la funcion de borrar y que pueda acceder al id para borrar el documento

asi se ve el firestore ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el id cuando recuperas todos los registros y cambiar tu código algo así y ahi ya tienes el id para poder eliminar

```
const obtenerServicios = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "Tobi"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const docs = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setDia(docs);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerServicios();
  }, []);



    const borrarFirestore = async (id) => {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "Tobi", id));
    };

borrarFirestore(id);// así deberías llamar al momento de eliminar
```

Comment: buenas, ya habia intentado asi y tampoco puedo  `    const q = query(collection(db, "Tobi"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const docs = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        docs.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      setDia(docs);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    obtenerServicios();
    setTimeout(setLoading, 1000, false);
  }, []);

  const borrarServicio = async () => {
    const borrarFirestore = async (dia) => {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, `${coleccion}`, dia.id));
    };
    borrarFirestore();`

Comment: Lo que pude hacer fue crear otro state que se llama id y setearle el doc.id , luego en la funcion de borrar paso el state id y ahi puedo borrar, pero no se borra donde hago click, sino que se va borrando desde el ultimo al primero

Comment: De la forma que lo hiciste de agregar un nuevo estado no esta correctamente ya que cada interaccione ion del forEach vas a ir agregando un nuevo id y al finalizar siempre te va a quedar el ultimo id del ultimo item

Comment: el coding que acabas de poner de eliminar no deberías tener otra función dentro de otra sino hacerle como esta en el ejemplo que puse y llamar desde el botón que elimina ejemplo <button onClick={() => borrarFirestore(dia.id)}>{{ dia.label }}</button>

Comment: lo probe asi pero sigue sin funcionarme, el problema esta en que no se por que razon no puedo acceder al id